# Zapier: Updating an Existing Field to blank/null in Process Street

Tags: zapier

How do you use a zap to remove data from an existing field? For example, the fields "Name" and "Email" have data, but I need a zap that will just set those values as blank/null/empty.

The zap I'm using is for a Checklist in Process Street. There are several fields (i.e., email, name, etc.) that are already populated with data in the Checklist, and I want to remove those data. Of course if you just leave the fields blank in the zap, Zapier ignores them in the update. I've tried looking up environment variables but can't find anything, and blind guessing with inserting a space, "", {{NULL}}, " ", doesn't work. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The empty string will work in many cases, but if it's acting up, you could try adding a Formatter step and replacing the existing contents of the field (using the field you want to clear from an earlier step as the "find" part of find/replace) with the empty string (the replace part of find/replace). You can see this document for how the Formatter by Zapier app can be used:

https://zapier.com/apps/formatter/help#reformatting-text

This is a bit quirky, so if that doesn't work, you might try reaching out to customer service. They'll definitely have more specific advice for your Zap.

https://zapier.com/app/contact-us

Comment: Appreciate it but it still doesn't work for me (it's clever and may work for others). I'm tracking the problem to being with Process Street, will post back when I find a solution

Comment: Process Street is aware of the issue, and has no fix at this time. It is not a problem with Zapier, it has to do with how process street handles data.